# Solid black border somehow fades when adding a border-left

Tags: html, css

I have created a very simple testcase demonstrating my issue (reproducable in both Firefox and Chrome, suggesting this is somehow intentional)

```css
div
{   
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 250px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div>text</div>
```

If you run the above snippet I hope you'll notice the black border is far from solid, and actually becomes heavily faded on the left side. Why?

Comment: Because its been stretched to 250px wide?

Comment: @j08691 what is? Not the left border; that's supposed to be white

Comment: try increasing the border-width in  `border: 1px solid black` :)

Comment: just a curious question, do you really need a `border-left` with the width of 250px? That could be solved in other ways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're experiencing can easily be explained when the initial border widths are changed slightly.
Borders attach to one another diagonally and having a very long left border stretches the diagonal connection out. Antialiasing leads to the fadeout you've described.

```css
div {
  border: 5px solid blue;
  border-left: 25px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>text</div>
```

As a continuous example of the fadeout being created:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  border-left-width: 2px;
}

div:nth-child(3) {
  border-left-width: 5px;
}

div:nth-child(4) {
  border-left-width: 10px;
}

div:nth-child(5) {
  border-left-width: 25px;
}

div:nth-child(6) {
  border-left-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>text</div>
<div>text</div>
<div>text</div>
<div>text</div>
<div>text</div>
<div>text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right, it is expected behavior. It's caused by transition of width between left border and bottom/top border. The reason it looks like it becomes more transparent, rather than thin is because width of bottom-left border is between 0-1px, therefore antialiasing kicks in to make it smoother (you can't display for example 0.5px).

I'm not sure if I can describe it in a clean way, so I made a [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zdgmoe) for you that hopefully explains how and why it happens.

html:

```
<div>text</div>
```

css:

```
html {
  background-color: yellow;
}
div {   
  border: 200px solid black;
  border-left: 200px solid green;

  transition: border 5s ease-out;
}

html:hover div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 200px solid white;
}
```